# Убирать input и сохранять значение в td js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

При нажатии на td появляется input с его координатами, как сделать так что бы после ввода других значений input удалялся и значение сохранялось, интересует чистый js без jquery. Вот код:

```
var d = document,
       td = d.getElementsByTagName('td');

       Object.keys(td).map( function(item) {

            var coordinates = td[item].getBoundingClientRect();
                td[item].innerHTML = coordinates.left + coordinates.top + coordinates.right + coordinates.bottom;

           var input = document.createElement('input');
               input.setAttribute('type','text');
               input.value = td[item].innerHTML;


            td[item].addEventListener("click", function(){
                td[item].innerHTML = "";
                td[item].appendChild(input);
           },false);

       });
```

Comment: Как пытались решить? С чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Да, стоит уточнить, в чем проблема или чего не хватает в вашем коде. А то получается "нужно сделать штуку, вот мой код" и сидите сами разбирайтесь и думайте, есть ли проблемы в коде и где они.

Answer (score 1):

Вставляете в ячейку `input`, присваиваете для него `display:none`. Потом для действия `onclick` по `td` пишите:

```
document.getElementById("yourTD").style.display = "block";
```